# drop draggable div just after confirm dialog message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a .drag div  and when I drop this div inside the .drop div the .drag div is removed.

But I just want to remove the .drag div if the user click in "ok" in a dialog message. I am trying to do this in the `drop:function(event,ui){...}`, but its not working.

Do you see how to solve this?

I have here the example that Im working on: http://jsfiddle.net/8t9v5tpq/12/

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  drag: function(event, ui) {      
  }    
});

$('.drop').droppable({ 
 });

drop: function(event, ui) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
          alert("You have confirmed!");
           ui.draggable.remove();
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          // revert the element to original position
        }
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
```

Comment: pls fix your fiddle it has error

Comment: The fiddle it isnt working with the dialog code inside droppable. What is the other error that you are talking? I update the fiddle, and now it is working, but without the part of dialog confirmation..

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a native confirm dialog:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    drag: function(event, ui) {

    }

});

$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    accept: ".drag",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))

            ui.draggable.css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        });
    }
});
```

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/8t9v5tpq/14/)